# Algorithmic Trading API

Tags: algorithmic-trading

Anyone have experience with algorithmic trading (like stocks)?  Any good services to use to get quotes and to make trades?

Comment: Is there some specific question re: "Algorithmic Trading" API's you are asking here?  This questions seems better suited for one of the many finance related communities on the net... try Cake Financial.

Comment: I was thinking specifically of brokerages that offered APIs, or services that allowed you to query for information.  Wish you hadn't closed it...

Comment: Someone else can reopen if they disagree with my close.  I just don't see how there is a specific answer to this question that is programming related.  Just have the word algorithmic in the question doesn't make it programming related.

Comment: Heh, from the top question in the "Related" list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327/what-online-brokers-offer-apis it sounds like this question has been asked and answered quite satisfactorily before. :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a freelance project that used [Interactive Brokers](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/), which provided both a proprietary API as well as a FIX-based one. The proprietary API is somewhat painful to use (and they probably can't change it much, for compatibility), but you can easily code a "translation layer" to make it much more pleasant. I haven't tried the FIX-based API, so no comments there.

And yes, I reopened the question. I happen to think it's a fair question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I know [TradeStation](http://www.tradestation.com/default_2.shtm) is pretty popular.

Comment: TradeStation is pretty terrible as far as the API goes. Forget trying to use a decent language such as C# with it.

Comment: It got a bit better with 9.0 version, but not much... They kind-of started to shift towards .Net, but do not expect to call you C# code directly. You still have to write most of your code in EasyLanguage which is a joke, or you have to use C API which is ancient.

Comment: Any comment on TradeStation's WebAPI?