# Real life trading API

Tags: web-services, finance

Do you know an API that lets you trade with real life stock or currency?

If so, please describe your experience:

- ease of development
- commissions
- sandbox environment?
- etc.

Comment: And subvert Wall Street's control over the "cost" of trades?  Hahahaha.  That's funny.

Comment: @S.Lott-I assume you'd still pay the transaction fees.

Comment: They do exist, but the ones I have seen are crazy expensive.

Comment: Just don't accidentally code an infinite loop...

Comment: @ceejayoz-It would either be a really good day or a really bad day if you did! ... either way it would be a life changing event! ;-)

Comment: TD Ameritrade Client Library for .NET http://github.com/kriasoft/tdameritrade

Answer (score 36, accepted):

AFAIK, [TradeStation](http://www.tradestation.com/automated_trading/auto_trading.shtm) is the most famous of the lot. Most other trading softwares provide APIs (NinjaTrader, MetaStock etc). FWIW, there are even competitions of automated trading systems -- see [this](http://championship.mql4.com/).

Also, this is something that the exchange has to support and your broker has to allow. Most exchanges I know of, do not allow automated trading without prior permission.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think the MetaStock API allows you to make trades; their software is strictly Technical Analysis, so it just gets prices.

Comment: @Jeff Barger: There's some kludge: <http://www.elitetrader.com/vb/showthread.php?threadid=17343>

Comment: TradeStation also has an HTTP based api, check out the docs at: http://tradestation.github.io/webapi-docs/

Comment: we need an update on this answer; it can't be used for HFT right?

Comment: TradeStation needs a 50k deposit to get access to their API. Just so you know...

Comment: Interactive Brockers API is a trap, slowly eating enormous amount of development time. Their Client Portal Web API demo has an expired SSL certificate (expired 1 year ago). You can only have one login session at any time, any type of client (Trader, API and Web), So you can not follow your API activity. I could not reach their customer support yet. Things you can do with a simple API like Alpaca in a day will take weeks of workarounds with Interactive Brockers API

Answer (score 20):

There are many brokers who will give you access to an API which lets you trade. Obviously you will be paying commissions to them as well as the bid/ask spread which may be wider than the direct markets. They will all differ in the types of instrument that they allow you to trade.

If you want an easy way in, you can use shrink-wrapped software such as [Tradestation](http://www.tradestation.com/) (horrible proprietary language), [NinjaTrader](http://www.ninjatrader.com/) (a little better, C#-based), or [SmartQuant](http://www.smartquant.com/) (better, C#-based). These generally have pre-built interfaces to a number of brokerages who will actually execute the trades. [InteractiveBrokers](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/) also has a direct API but they have a reputation for being a pain to deal with.

I would recommend checking alternative forums, such as [EliteTrader](http://www.elitetrader.com) which has a wealth of information on the relative merits of different brokerages. There are also plenty of folks on there trading through APIs.

Comment: i think those services does not offer real time data :(

Answer (score 15):

Try TD Ameritrade - they have a nice API, relatively low trading fees, and a good help forum .  Link to their [API offering overview](http://www.tdameritrade.com/tradingtools/partnertools/api_dev.html).

Comment: TD Ameritrade has huge costs. I mean - why pay $10 per trade when you can use Interactive Brokers, and pay $1 per trade? Its no contest.

Comment: One reason, because Interactive Brokers has high account minimums. TD is like $100 or something ridiculously small.

Comment: TD Ameritrade Client Library for .NET github.com/kriasoft/tdameritrade

Comment: This can be good for just getting real time quotes for free.

Comment: EDIT: It seems like there's a $25,000 account minimum to access their APIs...

Answer (score 12):

Most electronic stock exchanges don't provide an API, they provide a message specification. To get them to accept your messages (i.e. to trade directly with them), you will have to spend a very large amount of money.  and become a member of the exchange - that's what IBs do. Even a live market data feed (which you would need in order trade sensibly) can be ridiculously expensive.

Comment: Correct.  You must be a member to trade directly, so effectively you are talking to an API for a 'broker/dealer' that talks to another API directly to the exchange.  The exchanges make a good portion of their money from selling real time data feeds.

Answer (score 11):

This is similar to a question I asked a couple of years ago: [What online brokers offer APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327/what-online-brokers-offer-apis)

I would recommend looking into [Interactive Brokers](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/), which is the one I ended up choosing. [Their API](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/pagemap/pagemap_APISolutions.php) supports multiple languages including Java, C++, ActiveX and Excel's DDE. You can effectively do just about anything via the API that you can do using their fairly robust trading platform.

As a broker alone it's hard to beat IB's crazy low commissions (most of my orders are so low they get rounded up to the $1 minimum commission per order). Combine that with a fairly straightforward API and it's hard to beat.

Also, take a look at my question (linked above, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327/what-online-brokers-offer-apis)) for more information on brokers that offer APIs.

Comment: Just to add to what was said about InteractiveBrokers, they are high commissions if you trade a lot of shares, e.g. more than 1500. The commissions are per-share traded. They have commission examples of $150,000 on their website for trading millions of shares.

Comment: To add to Anon's comment, the commissions are here: http://individuals.interactivebrokers.com/en/p.php?f=commission  (For US is is 0.005 USD/share, with a max of 0.5% of trade value; so a $150K commission implies buying 30 million shares of something...)

Comment: To my knowledge IB API connects to their program while it is running on your desktop. It does not seem very useful really...

Answer (score 7):

I've just started playing around with [TradeKing's](http://www.tradeking.com/) API. Its dead simple and uses oauth. The $5 trade commission isn't bad either.

E-trade also has an api, but you have to go through some hoops to get production access. They also provide realtime streaming via a comet interface. There don't seem to be any libraries out there for etrade either except for the java ones etrade provides.

Comment: You have to be US citizen...

Answer (score 6):

https://www.quantopian.com

i suppose the newest, but has an online ide / debugger / visualizer, and integration with interactive brokers for paper trading and real trading.   great community for R&D too

Comment: Quantopian does not let you live trade, only test your algorithm, which is not the same.

Comment: quantopian does let you live trade + paper trade via an integration with interactive brokers (IB).   you need an IB account though.

Comment: Thanks for the correction :) Is it limited to IB? Any other broker?

Comment: IB only, and you need to fund your IB account to paper trade, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

Go through the links on [this page](http://ta-lib.org/hdr_lnk.html).

Lists a number of open source api's. Haven't tried any yet, but planning to check out active-quant.

Answer (score 2):

Contact your target Stock Exchange for trading API and test server. If your target Stock Excnage is on OMX platform, you will be provided with X-Stream API (unmanaged c++) and docs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an API for working with ETrade and some of the other trading software. I don't think you're going to find an API for executing trades without making use of a commercial product, though. If you're trying to do some analysis of trades, though, there are APIs available for retrieving quotes, listening to ticks, getting historical data for a symbol, etc. As I said at the beginning, many of the existing commercial products have an API for writing code to work with them.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to take a look at [**TD Ameritrade .NET SDK**](https://github.com/kriasoft/tdameritrade) hosted at Github

Answer (score 0):

I have used NinjaTrader and MetaTrader to trade currencies and futures products.

Ninja trader is very easy to use. I don't have super in depth coding skills although I can hold my own, and it worked for me just fine.

Their application is free to download. They have also created an "app" where you can choose different technical indicators to create trading strategies.

Having traded for awhile using automated systems, winning and losing, I would highly suggest using TICK DATA when you trade. Automated trading in the sense where you are using technical indicators to make your trading decisions is very competitive and very fast. Meaning, if you are using data such as 1min data, you are going to be behind the profitable trades, if there are any for your system.

I can tell you that as a day trader, the days of sitting at your screen and trading when the 1 min moving average crosses the 10 min, or something similar to that, are over. Not to say longer term strategies don't work, they do, on the daily charts.

My point is, use tick data no matter what platform you use. Ninja Trader is pretty good. Sign up for the tick data, and use that to trade. You'll have a better shot at being profitable if you are using technical indicators.