# Automating Etrade

Tags: python, automation, stocks, trading, broker

Hey everyone, I was wondering how would I start programming an interface to trading stocks in Etrade in python. I am attempting to make an automated trading bot, but there is no api publicly available for automated trading with Etrade. Thanks in advance. ^^

Comment: Etrade now has an API: https://us.etrade.com/e/t/activetrading/api

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For E-trade I could only find this: http://code.google.com/p/pyetrade/ . It uses urllib2 to access the site like a user would. But because of lack of an official API there is no guarantee that anything will keep working.

Interactive Brokers has an extensive API for automatic trading, also from Python. I can confirm that one works.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by "[What online brokers offer APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327/what-online-brokers-offer-apis)", [etrade has an api now](https://us.etrade.com/e/t/activetrading/api).

Answer (score 2):

Etrade has developer APIs now, they also have sample applications for java and python.

https://developer.etrade.com/home

Answer (score 0):

https://apisb.etrade.com/docs/api/account/api-account-v1.html

Fairly stable API, although some of the documented features don't work (all the XML returns work, but JSON returns are spotty)
pyetrade interface (https://github.com/jessecooper/pyetrade) works well and has been stable for many years.