# Do you know (ETF) trading platform that has robust API for JAVA?

Tags: java, api, trading

I am lookong for some broker that allows ETF trading, and have trader with API for java.
I found http://www.deltastock.com/ , but it seems they do not have java API. They have something like API for VBA and C#, but I cannot see the way how use their API in java. Their API has something to do with ActiveX - http://www.deltastock.com/english/platforms/forex-api.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327/what-online-brokers-offer-apis) post would be a good starting point. If you are interested in **ETFs** IB would be the best. They are generic broker where you can also trade ETFs.