# Is it possible to use some API from within R to place a stock trade via an online broker (e.g., Zecco or Fidelity)

Tags: r, finance

I know R and I am heavy user of Fidelity stock trading. I wonder if some R powerusers were able to find a broker which has an API and there is some sample R code to start with. Any broker is fine and any fees are fine - i would like simply to know if it is even possible. (even I have to pay a hefty monthly fee or something)

Answer (score 7):

[Interactive brokers](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/p.php?f=programInterface) has an API which you can access w/ various languages and Jeff Ryan has written a [package on CRAN to do extend that to R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IBrokers/index.html). I haven't used them so I don't know what their fees are but the setup for the IBrokers packages seems sensible. Caveat emptor: program trading at medium frequency beats lighting your money on fire as a trading strategy, but only just. ;)

Comment: thanks. I am wondering if IBrokers is my only option from within R.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327/what-online-brokers-offer-apis) is another question about brokers and APIs.

Comment: I've had multiple people recommend Interactive Brokers, but I think it's really just the best of  bad lot. I found both their sign-up process and their API to be kinda horrible.

Answer (score 3):

tradeking.com (which merged with or bought Zecco) has a RESTful API...a pretty nice one. I'm using it, and it's very simple to get started. They also have really low fees.

Comment: yea i like their streaming api